# Simplifying trigonometric summation: $ x[n] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{\sin \left( 2 \pi k M \frac{a}{b} n \right)}{\pi k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

I was reading an engineering publication and attempting to follow the math and got stuck at this "easy to show but somewhat lengthy" step.  The author starts with
$$
x[n] = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{\sin \left( 2 \pi k M \frac{a}{b} n \right)}{\pi k}
$$
where $a,b,M,k,n$ are integers.  The claim is that when letting
$$
\hat{b} = \frac{b}{\gcd(M,b)}
$$
and if $\hat{b}$ is even, then
$$
x[n] = \sum_{k=1}^{\hat{b}/2} \frac{(-1)^k}{\hat{b} \tan \left( \pi k / \hat{b} \right)} \sin \left( 2 \pi \frac{k \hat{M} a}{\hat{b}} n \right).
$$
I tried splitting into partial sums but could come up with nothing absolutely convergent.  I saw several questions that refer to complex analysis when dealing with these types of summation series, which I have no experience in.  If that is the route required then I will grab a text.  Wanted to know if there was some "easy" or "obvious" thing that I missed.  I will note that the author said he used the "antisymmetry" of sine to accomplish this reduction.

Comment: Also, I should have noted that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your author is trying to do.  The sum is simple to evaluate in terms of the given parameters as follows.

Write the sum as

$$f(y) =\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{\sin{\pi y k}}{\pi k} $$

Then if we take the derivative of $f$, the sum is easy to evaluate:

$$f'(y) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k \cos{\pi y k} $$

Write in terms of a complex exponential:

$$f'(y) = \Re{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^k e^{i \pi y k} } $$

This is simply a geometric series with sum

$$f'(y) = -\Re{\frac{e^{i \pi y}}{1+ e^{i \pi y}}}$$

which can be rewritten as

$$f'(y) = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Integrating with respect to $y$:

$$f(y) = -\frac{y}{2}+ C $$

with $C$ being a constant of integration, which may be found to be zero upon noting that $f(0)=0$.  Therefore, using the constants provided in lieu of $y$, we get that the sum is

$$ x[n] = -\pi M \frac{a}{b} n  $$

Comment: The author is trying to derive the number of "tones" to be expected over one period of n.  When $k$ goes from 1 to $\infty$ is looks like we should expect an infinite number of spectra, but he is arguing that the summation simplifies to $\hat{b}$ number of tones.  Also, I am not sure I can take the derivative and compute in that manner since $x[n]$ is a discrete function and $f(y)$ is a continuous function.  Perhaps I can better phrase the question?

Comment: @dcdo: what I did was a trick that allowed me to manipulate the sum so I could evaluate it.  $x[n]$ being discrete has no bearing; in fact, the final result still references $n$.  As for the author, what is the publication?

Comment: "Noise Spectra of Digital Sine-Generators Using the Table-Lookup Method", by Soenke Mehrgardt, IEEE Transactions on Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, Volume 31, Issue 4, August 1983.  I downloaded through IEEExplore through my university

Comment: Thanks.  I do not have access, but I'll try to see the context somehow.

Comment: I can take the equations and put them into MATLAB for a sanity check.  I could not find it with a Google search, so apparently it is only downloadable from behind a paywall.  I will report back the results.

Comment: Terrific!  I look forward to finding what you learn.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/a/img441/4695/xnandfy.png is a plot of the original $x[n]$ and $f(y)$.  This is for $M=8$, $b=256$, $a=3$, and $k=1$ to 2000.  $x[n]$ is a Fourier series of a sawtooth, so the plot looks correct.  $f(y)$ looks different and does not look like a sawtooth.  I do not know enough math to explain why your computation resulted in a different result.  My intuition tells me that we would see your result as an incredibly compact expression to represent a sawtooth waveform if this were possible.

Comment: Dcdo: I'm afraid I found an error with my result, in taking the derivative.  The sum should be over cosine, not sine.  I am a little embarrassed and will fix the entry.

Comment: Fixed it.  It explains the straight line you see, but check the details.

Comment: The final x[n] in the analysis cannot be positive for positive n, but the original x[n] definitely can be positive (see plot). Is the issue in the geometric series sum?  Also, I am also still not convinced that using the continuous function $f(y)$ to compute the discrete function $x[n]$ works in this case. Though I obviously have no idea how go forward here, hence the question in the first place.

Comment: I found another error in sign, so $x[n]$ is nonpositive for pos $n$.  This should fit your data.  I amaze myself sometimes with my capacity to make really dumb mistakes and I apologize for wasting your time with that other expression.  Please understand that $f(y)$ is a construct for evaluating the sum.  It is continuous for purely mechanical reasons.  Don't read too much into it.